# How to parse the below xml string using linq to xml?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-sql

**XML:**

```
<shift_details>
    <shift_time>10:00 to 10:30</shift_time>
    <count>0</count>
    <shift_time>10:30 to 11:00</shift_time>
    <count>0</count>
    <shift_time>11:00 to 11:30</shift_time>
    <count>0</count>
    <shift_time>11:30 to 12:00</shift_time>
    <count>0</count>
    <shift_time>12:00 to 12:30</shift_time>
    <count>0</count>
</shift_details>
```

**Code:**

```
var slots = from c in xmlResponse.Descendants("shift_details")
            select new TimeSlots
            {
                time = (string)c.Element("shift_time"),
                count = (string)c.Element("count"),
            };
```

The above code return only one slot item as output .but my xml contains too many records.

How to read all records in above xml?

Comment: I believe you mean linq to xml

Comment: If you control the structure of the XML I would change the XML because it's not structured correctly

Answer (score 5):

That's because `Element` returns only first element with given name. **You should consider changing your XML structure to separate different slots from each other**, e.g.:

```
<shift_details>
    <shift>
        <shift_time>10:00 to 10:30</shift_time>
        <count>0</count>
    </shift>
    (...)
</shift_details>
```

And then query it like that:

```
var slots = from c in xmlResponse.Element("shift_details").Elements("shift")
            select new TimeSlots
            {
                time = (string)c.Element("shift_time"),
                count = (string)c.Element("count"),
            };
```

Or if you can't change XML, you can still query it, but it will be a bit more tricky:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("Input.txt");
var details = doc.Root;

var times = details.Elements("shift_time");
var counts = details.Elements("count");

var slots = times.Zip(counts, (t, c) => new { time = (string)t, count = (string)c }).ToList();
```

Comment: Nice use of Zip (assuming that the XML always has the same number of shift_time and count elements.

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand if you can't change the structure of the XML, you'll need to start getting creative (although I don't recommend it). In this case you'd probably be ok (even if less maintainable in the long run) with something like this, which takes a collection of elements and splits them into chunks each containing unique elements:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<XElement>> Partition(this IEnumerable<XElement> elements)
    {
        var currentList = new List<XElement>();
        var tags = new HashSet<string>();

        foreach (var xElement in elements)
        {
            if (tags.Contains(xElement.Name.LocalName))
            {
                yield return currentList.ToArray();
                currentList.Clear();
                tags.Clear();
            }

            currentList.Add(xElement);
            tags.Add(xElement.Name.LocalName);
        }

        yield return currentList.ToArray();
    }
}
```

You can then run the collection of children under the shift_details through this and obtain fairly easy to process groups. Should be straight-forward from here.